# How to count instances per ID per day in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to count all the unique ID's per Date in R. However, I don't know how I can achieve this.

Currently I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
ID DateTime
2  2019-10-6
4  2019-10-6
3  2019-10-6
4  2019-10-6
3  2019-10-9
2  2019-10-9
2  2019-10-9
```

From this, I tried to get a dataframe to get the following result:

```
ID DateTime    Count
2  2019-10-6   1
3  2019-10-6   1
4  2019-10-6   2
2  2019-10-9   2
3  2019-10-9   1
```

However, I tried many variations working with aggregate *aggregate* functions, but whenever I try them I get errors like the following:

```
  Error in UseMethod("summarise_") : 
  no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "Date"
```

My R is a little bit rusty, but I have no idea how to achieve this and searching the internet didn't help either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); df1 %>% count(ID, DateTime)` or `table(df1[c('ID', 'DateTime")])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy solution with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

dates <- c("2019-10-6","2019-10-6","2019-10-6","2019-10-6","2019-10-9","2019-10-9","2019-10-9")
id <- c(2,4,3,4,3,2,2)

dat<-tibble(id,dates)

dat %>%
  count(id,dates)
```

Comment: Oh my, so stupid of me. It worked! I was so focussed on using aggregate functions and trying to make factors or something like that, that I forgot to use that! Many thanks my friend!

Answer (score 3):

And this can (of course) also be done the `data.table` way

```
dt <- fread("ID DateTime
2  2019-10-6
4  2019-10-6
3  2019-10-6
4  2019-10-6
3  2019-10-9
2  2019-10-9
2  2019-10-9")

dt[, .( count = .N), by = .(ID, DateTime)][]

#    ID  DateTime count
# 1:  2 2019-10-6     1
# 2:  4 2019-10-6     2
# 3:  3 2019-10-6     1
# 4:  3 2019-10-9     1
# 5:  2 2019-10-9     2
```

Answer (score 2):

`aggregate` is not that difficult to use, just remember that you need something to aggregate, in the case below, the data frame's row names. I coerce the `dates` column to class `"Date"`.

```
dates <- as.Date(c("2019-10-6","2019-10-6","2019-10-6","2019-10-6","2019-10-9","2019-10-9","2019-10-9"))
id <- c(2,4,3,4,3,2,2)

dat<-data.frame(id,dates)
aggregate(row.names(dat) ~ id + dates, dat, length)
#  id      dates row.names(dat)
#1  2 2019-10-06              1
#2  3 2019-10-06              1
#3  4 2019-10-06              2
#4  2 2019-10-09              2
#5  3 2019-10-09              1
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the function I was looking for at first. I never knew you could do "value ~ value + value" where you could call a function of a value + a value. I already accepted another answer because he was first and the dplyr function was shorter, but you also deserve the accept/upvotes.